# Visual Studio Debug Symbols

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, uwp, debug-symbols

I am developing a little UWP app in C# and recently VisualStudio 2019 CE started to misbehave.
It can not show any debug information regarding any external code with the following message. Debugging my own code works fine but any library code can not be found.

[image]
This makes debugging incredible difficult, not to say impossible. I already tried the common things like restarting, reseting vs, etc.

If anybody would have a suggestion or knows what is going on here, I would be really glad.

Comment: if you reference a .net standard 2.0 project for some kind of shared code, change PDB type to portable for .net standard dll and the UWP app.

Comment: any update on this? Do you use .net standard 2.0 lib or not?

Comment: No I´m not using a .NET standard library

Answer (score 0):

> Debugging my own code works fine but any library code can not be found.

For your description, it looks you have checked just my code option within Visual Studio. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019), To  disable **Just My Code** in Visual Studio, under Tools > Options (or Debug > Options) > Debugging > General, select or deselect Enable Just My Code.

Comment: I already tried that. Gives me the same error that the symbols have not been  loaded or there is no information regarding the code in those symbols

Comment: Please find the project of the solution and checking Properties > Build > Advanced > Output - Debugging Information to **Full**.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but that is already set to full

Comment: Could you show the project  debug type in the project Debug option?

Comment: If you meant those settings, here is a screenshot
https://gyazo.com/20d60cfe67cfb0165a951aff71f30345

Comment: Yep, please try to edit it to mixed model and test again.

Comment: I tried this and now it tells me the following "The runtime refused to evaluate this expression", and Visual Studio becomes unresponsive for 5 seconds everytime I want to inspect variables

Comment: It's strange, Can you test with VisualStudio 2017?

Comment: Tried running the application in VS17 -> Gives me the following errors
https://gyazo.com/988ebd2fa7aff93fceff1c5770d5901a

I am starting to hate VS...

Comment: Besides, 1. try to enable `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` under `Tools`-->`Options`-->`Debugging`-->`General`. 2. close VS Instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder, `bin`, `obj` folder, then restart your project again to test it.